# Easeljs project build support to android with cocoonjs

Tags: android, cordova, easeljs, cocoonjs

i have created a application using easeljs. the canvas works good in ios but the performance is very slow in android with phonegap. as looked in [cocoonjs](http://www.ludei.com/tech/cocoonjs) i dint get it work with easeljs.
can any one suggest me do better build android apk with easeljs source...!

Comment: What exactly didn't work with cocoonJS? (what does the cocoonjs debugger say?) I've created apps with easeljs+cocoonjs before, the only issues I experienced where with sound(soundjs) and touch - I wrote a couple fixes for those issues, if you could be more specific about what's not working.

Comment: i was getting a black screen by installing apk provided by cocoonjs launcher. will you please tell me the project structure of easeljs for cocoonjs launcher

Comment: You should download the Launcher-App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideateca.cocoonjslauncher&hl=en  there you can load your app via a ZIP-file and debug it live with a debug-console and everything, I'm sure you will get an error output there